# SIte logo is not displaying

Tags: theme-development, logo

Am trying to display site logo in my website, which i have uploaded under site-logo section comes under theme->customize->logo->publish

I have added following code in functions.php for support

```
function theme_prefix_setup() {

    add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'      => 100,
        'width'       => 400,
        'flex-width' => true,
    ) );

}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'theme_prefix_setup' );
```

Following code in header.php to display logo

```
<a class="footer_link" href="index.php"><img src="<?php echo the_custom_logo(); ?>/assets/images/logo.png" /></a>
```

But logo is not displaying ,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`the_custom_logo()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_custom_logo/) *displays a custom logo image, linked to home*, so you don't need to echo it, wrap it inside `a` tag or use it as a `src` for an image.

If you want to use the default output, then just use  in your theme file. If there's no custom logo set, then the function results in an empty string i.e. nothing is displayed.

For custom output, first get the custom logo image ID with `get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' )` and then get the image markup with `wp_get_attachment_image()`. Or the logo image url with `wp_get_attachment_url()` or `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.

Example with fallback, modified from how `get_custom_logo()` works.

```
$custom_logo_id = get_theme_mod( 'custom_logo' );
if ( $custom_logo_id ) {
  $custom_logo_attr = array(
    'class' => 'custom-logo',
  );
  printf(
    '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home">%2$s</a>',
    esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
    wp_get_attachment_image( $custom_logo_id, 'full', false, $custom_logo_attr );
  );
} else {
  $custom_logo_attr = array(
    'class' => 'fallback-logo',
  );
  printf(
    '<a href="%1$s" class="custom-logo-link" rel="home">%2$s</a>',
    esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ),
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/images/logo.png'
  );
}
```